# Pass cookies to Android WebView

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I have a web service. Normally I give a connection with HttpURLConnection. Here's one I need.
Connect with HttpURLConnection and get session and cookie information   from the HttpURLConnection  and open WebView.
in short
Input from within the application process whether android. I want to make the rest of the operations in WebView.

Comment: See [Pass cookies from HttpURLConnection (java.net.CookieManager) to WebView (android.webkit.CookieManager)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12731211/687315)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `CookieSyncManager` class. With google, I found this:

```
    CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(mWebView.getContext());
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();

    cookieManager.setCookie("http://xx.xxx.xxx.com","mid="+MySession.GetSession().sessionId+" ; Domain=.xxx.com");

    cookieSyncManager.sync();


    String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie("http://xx.xxx.xxx.com");

    Log.d(LOGTAG, "cookie ------>"+cookie);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new TuWebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://xx.xx.xxx.com");
```

Comment: I was sending unnecessary information. I deleted and solved.

Comment: Missing some stuf: MySession is undefined.