# Pass cookies from HttpURLConnection (java.net.CookieManager) to WebView (android.webkit.CookieManager)

Tags: android, cookies, android-webview, single-sign-on, httpurlconnection

> *I've seen answers about how this should work with the old `DefaultHttpClient`
>   but there's not a good example for [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)*

I'm using `HttpURLConnection` to make requests to a web application. At the start of the my Android application, I use `CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager())` to automatically deal with the session cookies, and this is working fine.

At some point after the login, I want to show live pages from the web application to the user with a `WebView` instead of downloading data behind the scenes with `HttpURLConnection`. However, I want to use the same session I established earlier to prevent the user from having to login again.

How do I copy the cookies from `java.net.CookieManager` used by `HttpURLConnection` to `android.webkit.CookieManager` used by `WebView` so I can share the session?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As compared with `DefaultHttpClient`, there are a few extra steps. The key difference is how to access the existing cookies in `HTTPURLConnection`:

1. Call `CookieHandler.getDefault()` and cast the result to `java.net.CookieManager`.
2. With the cookie manager, call `getCookieStore()` to access the cookie store.
3. With the cookie store, call `get()` to access the list of cookies for the given `URI`.

Here's a complete example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get cookie manager for WebView
    // This must occur before setContentView() instantiates your WebView
    android.webkit.CookieSyncManager webCookieSync =
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    android.webkit.CookieManager webCookieManager =
        CookieManager.getInstance();
    webCookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

    // Get cookie manager for HttpURLConnection
    java.net.CookieStore rawCookieStore = ((java.net.CookieManager)
        CookieHandler.getDefault()).getCookieStore();

    // Construct URI
    java.net.URI baseUri = null;
    try {
        baseUri = new URI("http://www.example.com");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // Handle invalid URI
        ...
    }

    // Copy cookies from HttpURLConnection to WebView
    List<HttpCookie> cookies = rawCookieStore.get(baseUri);
    String url = baseUri.toString();
    for (HttpCookie cookie : cookies) {
        String setCookie = new StringBuilder(cookie.toString())
            .append("; domain=").append(cookie.getDomain())
            .append("; path=").append(cookie.getPath())
            .toString();
        webCookieManager.setCookie(url, setCookie);
    }

    // Continue with onCreate
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am using above code to get httpUrlConnection cookies to pass it on webview. I am getting cookies from rawCookieStore properly. and setting cookie to cookiemanager. But the webview page is not getting that session onload of that page. Please help me out for the issue.

Answer (score 56):

I would like to suggest a completely different approach to your problem. Instead of copying cookies from one place to another (manual sync), let's make HttpURLConnection and WebViews use the **same** cookie storage.

This completely eliminates the need for sync. Any cookie updated in any one of them, will be immediately and automatically reflected in the other.

To do this, create your own implementation of java.net.CookieManager which forwards all requests to the WebViews' webkit android.webkit.CookieManager.

Implementation:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.CookiePolicy;
import java.net.CookieStore;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class WebkitCookieManagerProxy extends CookieManager 
{
    private android.webkit.CookieManager webkitCookieManager;

    public WebkitCookieManagerProxy()
    {
        this(null, null);
    }

    WebkitCookieManagerProxy(CookieStore store, CookiePolicy cookiePolicy)
    {
        super(null, cookiePolicy);

        this.webkitCookieManager = android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public void put(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders) throws IOException 
    {
        // make sure our args are valid
        if ((uri == null) || (responseHeaders == null)) return;

        // save our url once
        String url = uri.toString();

        // go over the headers
        for (String headerKey : responseHeaders.keySet()) 
        {
            // ignore headers which aren't cookie related
            if ((headerKey == null) || !(headerKey.equalsIgnoreCase("Set-Cookie2") || headerKey.equalsIgnoreCase("Set-Cookie"))) continue;

            // process each of the headers
            for (String headerValue : responseHeaders.get(headerKey))
            {
                this.webkitCookieManager.setCookie(url, headerValue);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, List<String>> get(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders) throws IOException 
    {
        // make sure our args are valid
        if ((uri == null) || (requestHeaders == null)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument is null");

        // save our url once
        String url = uri.toString();

        // prepare our response
        Map<String, List<String>> res = new java.util.HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // get the cookie
        String cookie = this.webkitCookieManager.getCookie(url);

        // return it
        if (cookie != null) res.put("Cookie", Arrays.asList(cookie));
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public CookieStore getCookieStore() 
    {
        // we don't want anyone to work with this cookie store directly
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

and finally use it by doing this on your application initialization:

```
android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.createInstance(appContext);
// unrelated, just make sure cookies are generally allowed
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

// magic starts here
WebkitCookieManagerProxy coreCookieManager = new WebkitCookieManagerProxy(null, java.net.CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(coreCookieManager);
```

Comment: If the server tries to delete cookies with expires as a date in the past, then this solution will not succeed in deleting the cookie. This is clearly mentioned in the javadoc [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setCookie(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)) "The cookie being set will be ignored if it is expired." I also verified the same in Android 4.2.1 device.

Comment: I am using this solution in my app, however I defer creating the instance of the proxy until I am actually logging into the server. On my app start up I clear any existing cookies using "CookieManager mgr = android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance(); mgr.removeAllCookie();". On API 17 (4.2.2) this crashes my app with "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call CookieSyncManager::createInstance() or create a webview before using this class".  I surely don't want to create an instance of CookieSyncManager as the above proxy solution isn't using the CookieSyncManger. How do I resolve this crash?

Answer (score 11):

I magically solved all my cookie problems with this one line in onCreate:

`CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());`

Comment: This worked for me too. Thanks! That's also what Google says here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: Now in above call new CookieManager() are you instantiating android.webkit.CookieManager or java.net.CookieManager?

Comment: @SubodhNijsure java.net.CookieManager

Comment: YOU THERE, SAVED MY LIFE ! THANKS

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, and this is my solution :

Just after login (it's important because before, you may be don't have cookie yet) using httpurlconnection POST (after getResponseCode), I do :

```
 responseCode = connexion.getResponseCode();
 if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
     final String COOKIES_HEADER = "Set-Cookie";
     cookie = connexion.getHeaderField(COOKIES_HEADER);
     ...
 }
```

(where cookie is a public String in my class)

And in the webview activity, where I want to display a web page from server using WebView, I do :

```
    String url = "http://toto.com/titi.html";        // the url of the page you want to display
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getActivity());
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
    android.webkit.CookieManager cookieManager = android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
    cookieManager.setCookie(url, cookie);
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```

As my webview is in a fragment, I had to use getActivity() for the Context, I also had to specify android.webkit. before CookieManager otherwise it cannot be resolved (import java.net instead of android.webkit cookie manager).

cookie is the same String as above (in my Fragment, I had to recover it using :

```
    cookie = getArguments().getString(COOKIE);
```

and in my MainActivity, I send it by :

```
    Bundle arg = new Bundle();
    arg.putString(Fragment_Cameras.COOKIE, cookie);
    fragment.setArguments(arg);
```

I hop this can help !