# Android Share cookie with Webview and Volley request

Tags: android

I have searched through a lot of answers and implemented one which helped me with maintaining cookies in volley request.

Code which helped me is following

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
```

That code has helped me maintain same session with all volley request.

Right after this code I open a webview in `onCreate` method. Webview has different session and not shared with volley request.

How can I make sure that both has same session.

Following is my `onCreate` method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    /* Dialog view */
    LinearLayout linearLayoutProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutProgressBar);
    // Creates instance of the manager.

    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    WebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new WebViewClientImpl(this, linearLayoutProgressBar);
    webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

    webAppInterface = new WebAppInterface(this, webView);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(webAppInterface, "Android");

    webView.loadUrl(AppConstants.mobileUrl);

    //GetLocation function fetches the location and sends it to server.
    //So first webview is opened and then data is sent to server.
    getLocation();
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use `CookieManager`. The issue is that there are many `CoockieManager` depending on the context used. With Volley it is `java.net.CookieManager` and with WebView it is `android.webkit.CookieManager`. Both are not compatible with each other.
The solution I found here is to create your own CookieManager extended from `java.net.CookieManager`. The goal is to send the request to the `android.webkit.CookieManager`in the same time. Like this, both are synchronized.

Juste create the following class as is :

```
public class WebkitCookieManagerProxy extends CookieManager
{
    private android.webkit.CookieManager webkitCookieManager;

    public WebkitCookieManagerProxy()
    {
        this(null, null);
    }

    public WebkitCookieManagerProxy(CookieStore store, CookiePolicy cookiePolicy)
    {
        super(null, cookiePolicy);
        this.webkitCookieManager = android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public void put(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders) throws IOException
    {
        // make sure our args are valid
        if ((uri == null) || (responseHeaders == null)) return;
        // save our url once
        String url = uri.toString();
        // go over the headers
        for (String headerKey : responseHeaders.keySet())
        {
            // ignore headers which aren't cookie related
            if ((headerKey == null) || !(headerKey.equalsIgnoreCase("Set-Cookie2") || headerKey.equalsIgnoreCase("Set-Cookie"))) continue;
            // process each of the headers
            for (String headerValue : responseHeaders.get(headerKey))
            {
                this.webkitCookieManager.setCookie(url, headerValue);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, List<String>> get(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders) throws IOException
    {
        // make sure our args are valid
        if ((uri == null) || (requestHeaders == null)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument is null");
        // save our url once
        String url = uri.toString();
        // prepare our response
        Map<String, List<String>> res = new java.util.HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        // get the cookie
        String cookie = this.webkitCookieManager.getCookie(url);
        // return it
        if (cookie != null) res.put("Cookie", Arrays.asList(cookie));
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public CookieStore getCookieStore()
    {
        // we don't want anyone to work with this cookie store directly
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

And finally, call once only, early in your code and before any https request :

```
WebkitCookieManagerProxy coreCookieManager = new WebkitCookieManagerProxy(null, java.net.CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(coreCookieManager);
```

After looking for a solution for a long time, I found it here: [Two way sync for cookies between HttpURLConnection (java.net.CookieManager) and WebView (android.webkit.CookieManager)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18057624/)

Answer (score 0):

From Volley Request, you have to take a cookie and store in shared preference.

then you can set the same cookie with your web view settings.

To retrieve cookie details from volley [refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16743595/13789671)

To set the cookie to web view URL like

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
} else {
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
}
cookieManager.setCookie(url, ${cookie});
webView.load(url);
```

Comment: I open the website first in WebView and then send volley request. Can I get cookie from webview and set it to volley or do I have to send volley request to server first, set cookie and then open webview url?

Comment: You can get all cookies from current url by this way from web view Client
                         `@Override        
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
    String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
}`