# How to combine PersistentCookieStore with Webkit CookieManager?

Tags: android, cookies, webview, android-webview, okhttp

I'm currently using `PersistentCookieStore`, as per shown in example here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34886860/3286489

However, since I need to synchronized my cookies with webview, it looks like the PersistentCookieStore as it is, doesn't get sync to the webkit Cookie Manager.

I found another link which gives the guide as https://stackoverflow.com/a/38775243/3286489

This overrides `CookieJar`, and not using the `JavaNetCookieJar` that `PersistentCookieStore` is using. How could I combine them both?

Comment: I end up writing a blog of my findings. https://medium.com/@elye.project/a-tale-on-android-cookies-store-management-b04832ca18c6