# Android - Use Volley cookies in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I created a `LoginActivity` which is connected to my REST API. I added there `CookieHandler` and `CookieManager` to use cookies in another activity. Everything works fine, I decided to remember user in SharedPreferences and I have a problem. The user is now redirecting directly to a new activity (which is OK), but this activity doesn't display anything because it needs to have cookies from LoginActivity. How can I solve this problem? I thought about adding cookies to SharedPreferenes but I don't know if it's a good way. Thanks in advance for a help!

Here is part of my `LoginActivity`:

```
val cookieManager = CookieManager()
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass cookies from HttpURLConnection (java.net.CookieManager) to WebView (android.webkit.CookieManager)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731211/pass-cookies-from-httpurlconnection-java-net-cookiemanager-to-webview-android)

Comment: You might also consider checking the link [here](https://medium.com/@elye.project/a-tale-on-android-cookies-store-management-b04832ca18c6)